# Chrome in the sky

Tags: google-chrome, cloud

A spot of googling has not thrown up anything immediately useful so I thought I would ask here.  Is there a way for me to test out my webapp on a number of different Chrome browsers running at remote locations?  I don't mean just getting back screenshots - rather being able to log in to the webapp in question, try out a few typical operations... .

In case the question isn't too clear - is there a Browser in the Cloud testing service rather like the Mac in a Cloud hire a virtual mac service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SauceLabs have what you need, but can be pretty pricey:

https://saucelabs.com/

Comment: Thanks, that sounds useful.  If you are familiar with the way they operate would you mind explaining a bit of their rather cutesy terminology.  For instance what does Manual Sauce mean?  All I want to do is to try out my webapp (which currently needs to run just Chrome) on a few other Chrome installations rather than my own local machines or ones belonging to friends etc. All in all I need less than an hour of access.

Comment: It is their witty way of trying to say, manual vs automated testing. SauceLabs is primarily about automated UI testing, so they restrict on how many minutes of *automated* testing you get for each price plan, but manual ('manual sauce') is generally unlimited. That is, how many minutes you get to click around your site manually. Does that make a bit more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.browserstack.com/

You can get a free trial on there and the (current) individual monthly cost is $19 USD.

Comment: Thank you, Andy.  Their local testing feature sounds useful.  There is one thing that bothers me - you get a pristine VM.  So the testing will identify issues related to the browser on its own.  A real machine might have a stack of other issues - related to specific browser plugins, the firewall being used etc which will be untestable this way?  Right?

Comment: I think the VM is only destroyed each time you stop the testing session. When you stop testing is up to you. From what I remember, the session lasts as long as the tunnel is connected. Sorry, it's been a while since I used it.